# PostgreSQL Delete Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table 1: Schema for the bookworm database. Primary keys are underlined. There are some foreign key references to link the tables together; you can make use of these with natural joins.

```
Author(aid, alastname, afirstname, acountry, aborn, adied).
Book(bid, btitle, pid, bdate, bpages, bprice).
City(cid, cname, cstate, ccountry).
Publisher(pid, pname).
Author_Book(aid, bid).
Publisher_City(pid, cid).
```

I have been trying to delete all books published after 1985 while deleting tuples from both the author_book and book tables, using only two delete statements.

So far I have tried..

```
delete from book
where bdate > 1985;
```

giving me the syntax:

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "book" violates foreign key constraint 
"author_book_bid_fkey" on table "author_book"
DETAIL:  Key (bid)=(cltl) is still referenced from table "author_book".
```

and...

```
delete from author_book
where bid > 1985;
```

with another syntax:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character > integer
LINE 2: where bid > 1985;
              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I know this is easier than I think, but just cant grasp what is going wrong. Look forward to hearing your input. This still isn't working can someone help please!!

Comment: "*Key (bid)=(cltl) is still referenced from table author_book*" is pretty clear: You have a foreign key to the table `author_book` and there is still a row in that table referencing the book you are trying to delete. You need to first delete the rows from `author_book` or declare the foreign key as `on delete cascade`

Comment: so something like "delete * from author_book;" first? @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
delete from book
where bdate = bdate > 1985;
```

to

```
delete from book
where bdate  > 1985;
```

the reason why it does not working is that  (bdate > 1985) returns a boolean value 
and you compare the boolean value to smallint.  Delete needs a true value from where to be executed. similar to the next issue

Comment: I tried that, look at my original post above as I have edited it. Thank you for your help, slowly but surely moving along.

Comment: first of all, book's bdate is a foreign key to other relations. you cannot just delete whatever you want in book without affecting our relations. so there is a foreign key constraint. second, bid  > 1985; compare a char type to int type. As a starter, you need to read the error messages and understand what is going in on